# Good practice to define hive.metastore.warehouse.dir: local fs or HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I'm installing Hive and I have to decide this parameter 
`hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` into the hive-site.xml.

I have installed Hadoop as a single node and my question here is about which option is better to set that parameter: in a local directory or HDFS directory?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would put it in an hdfs directory just in case you ever want to scale horizontally

Comment: Thanks for your comment!. And what of both is better option in relation with the performance?

Comment: If you have a standalone machine, local will be faster because at the end your hdfs is on top of local. If you are in a cluster your only option is hdfs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said **David Espart**, the best way is:

Set it locally, if is a single node.
Otherwise, in the HDFS because of is the only option.

Thanks!